# JWPlayer, Sharing and shoving jwsource=c to every share link

Tags: jwplayer

when you use the sharing options of JWPlayer there's a button under the "Share" icon for `Link`. This copies the current page URL onto the clipboard. However, it adds `?jwsource=c` to every URL.

The documentation allows us to override the `link`, but even when we do override the`sharing.link` setting, say to be `https://cnn.com` for testing purposes, it still adds the `?jwsouorce=c`, copying `https:/cnn.com?jwsource=c` to the clipboard.

I need a way to stop this from happening. I don't want `?jwsource=c` added every time. There seems to be no way of doing this in the documentation.

Has someone found a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the release of JW Player v8.24.4. the issue of `?jwsource=cl` being appended to any shared links has been resolved